# undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I know this error, i know what it means but in this case it makes absolutely no sense. I have a form that used to work well. And i have another form almost the same working nicely. However this form now gives me this error when i submit the data:

```
 Showing C:/Sites/mewwd/app/views/wine_lists/_form.html.erb where    ine #189 raised:
 undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass Rails
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.collection_select :wine_list_region_id, @regioes, :id, :regiao , {hide_label: true, :selected => @regioes.first.id} , {:style => "width: 120px",:required => true} %>
```

**Controller**

```
def new
@wine_list = WineList.new
@tipos = WineListType.where(:user_id => [current_user.id, "0"])
@produtores = WineListProducer.where(:user_id => [current_user.id, "0"])
@regioes = WineListRegion.where(:user_id => [current_user.id, "0"])
@dosagens = WineListPriceType.where(:user_id => [current_user.id, "0"])
end
```

This collection_select if fetching the data correctly! Everything show's up the way it should but when i submit i get that error and i dont understand why.

Comment: How are you rendering the partial?

Comment: <%= render 'form' %> u mean this?

Comment: Yes, and I see the problem. I will be posting an answer.

Comment: nice :) thank you!

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace as well as the code where the .first is blowing up please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why but if I put the

```
 @wine_list = WineList.new
 @tipos = WineListType.where(:user_id => [current_user.id, "0"])
 @produtores = WineListProducer.where(:user_id => [current_user.id, "0"])
 @regioes = WineListRegion.where(:user_id => [current_user.id, "0"])
 @dosagens = WineListPriceType.where(:user_id => [current_user.id, "0"])
```

in the create action it works.... i never did it, this is always in the new action but right now this works in the create action. If someone manages to explain to me why I'll accept the answer

Comment: That's just a guess, but you are most likely using one of these variables in the create action later (or maybe in callback). Try removing them one by one to find out which one. Another hint is that you are using method "first" on it. Also, you are using non-english variables names. That also may create an error (conventions and auto pluralizing and singularizing), but I don't think it's the case.

Comment: It's all of them.... all of them were creating the error.... and I didnt use them in create... trust me it's a mystery oO

Answer (score 0):

The form code depends on `@regioes` to supply a value for the form `collection_select`.  If `@regios` is not initialized, accessing the `first` method on it will cause the `nil:NilClass` error that you saw.

In a typical Rails application, the `new` method is used to setup the variables to render onto the view's form, and the `create` method is used to process the values entered on the form after they are submitted (via POST) to the controller.  `new` is for display; `create` is for saving.

The question implies that the action is happening on `new`, by showing the code in the `new` action of the controller, showing the form, and showing that the error occurs in the form.  The form certainly depends on `@regios` to have a value, and failing that, raises an exception.  This makes sense if `@regios` was never initialized in the `new` controller, although the code demonstrates that it is indeed initialized.

The subsequent information in the answer shows that initializing `@regios` and other values in the `create` action somehow causes the form to work.  This would imply that there is some non-standard association between the form and `create` that violates the separation of `GET` and `POST` actions.  This would be a troubling situation if the `create` method dealt with the form (or the view) in any way.

If the information is correct, and changes made to the `create` action somehow affect the form, then the `create` action has been involved in the `GET` action in an inappropriate way.  The cause of that should be investigated and resolved.  Not enough information has been provided here, as yet, to determine what the actual cause of that is.  This information would be required, at a minimum:

- Complete method bodies for the `new` and `create` actions
- Complete logs for *both* the `new` and `create` actions
- The route definitions for the `new` and `create` actions